# How to serialize POJO fields differently based on Accepts header

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson, marshalling

We have a POJO that contains a collection and have it annotated thus:

```
@XmlElement(name = "<MyId")
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "MyIds")
private final Set<Long> myIds;
```

We are using JacksonJaxbJsonProvider in CXF to do the marshalling in our REST service.

The problem we are seeing is that if someone requests application/xml the response is correct, in that the user gets:

```
<MyIds>
  <MyId>123</MyId>
  <MyId>456</MyId>
  ...
</MyIds>
```

But when application/json is requested, the user gets (note the singular field name):

```
{
  "MyId" : [123, 456, ...]
}
```

What I want to know is if there's a way to make that plural in the JSON response, and if so, how.

This feels like it may be bug in Jackson but there may be a perfectly good reason this is happening.  Also, I realize that if everyone used the same POJO, we wouldn't have to care about what the marshalled text looked like, but in this case, one of the consumers cannot use our POJO.

Comment: FYI - Here is how we handle this use case in MOXy:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/binding-to-json-xml-handling-collections.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan yea, that's exactly what we want, but we've adopted Jackson and are unable to switch.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using version 2.1 or above of Jackson there's a feature which can be enabled to get the behaviour you want

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper()
m.configure(MapperFeature.USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME, true);
```